# Error adding a svn repository location in Eclipse helios

Tags: svn

When i add a repository location in eclipse it shows "Location information has been specified incorrectly svn : E170001:PROPFIND of '/svn/  ': 403 Forbidden (http://   )" . I am new to SVN and Eclipse. When i try to access the repository through browser it aks for username and password and then shows the content of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I checked two things

1. IF apache has access to the the SVN repository. I checked the apache
   user and group by the commands

ps aux | grep apache2

groups apache-user-name

changed the user and group on the svn repository with user and group of apache.

2 Check for mod_evasive module

there was a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf
just commented the first line which was loading the mod_evasive module. The issue was resolved.
mod_evasive and mod_dav_svn which is used to access repository does not work together